# tqdm in screen environment printing new line and unknown charactors

Tags: shell, gnu-screen, tqdm

When I use `tqdm` in `screen`, it prints a new line indefinitely and unknown characters in the bar.

```
Epoch 0:   5%|��                           | 255/5474 [03:31<1:12:09,  1.21it/s]
Epoch 0:   2%|�                             | 90/5474 [01:24<1:23:46,  1.07it/s]
Epoch 0:   2%|�                             | 89/5474 [01:23<1:23:57,  1.07it/s]
```

I used `bash` as the default shell and added the following configurations

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8

root@35573c9f245c:~/git/pytorch-openai-transformer-lm# cat ~/.screenrc 
# ~/.screenrc
defshell -bash      # dash makes it a login shell
```

The same code works well in other terminals.

Any hint over this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

As you guessed, the problem is caused by the unknown characters. Running `screen` in UTF-8 mode will solve that:

```sh
screen -U
```

Answer (score 4):

When calling `tqdm`, try to include argument `ascii=True` in order to deal with `screen` not being UTF-8 friendly. Something like below:

```
for item in tqdm(items, total=len(items), ascii=True):
        pass
```